# What is the class of a spell cast from a staff?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

In D&D 5e when a character casts a spell from a staff (e.g. staff of a magi), what is the class of that spell? It is important for items like "+1 to DC for *this class* spells that you cast" from Tasha's.

Specific example:

- I am a lvl 20 Artificer.
- I am attuned to and holding a [Staff of Power](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-power), and casting Hold Monster from it.
- I am also attuned and holding in my other hand (let's say DM would allow my hand to hold all of them, this is just for illustration) all of the following:

  - +3 [All purpose tool](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/all-purpose-tool) (bonus to artificer spells I cast).
  - +2 [Arcane Grimoire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/arcane-grimoire) (bonus to wizard spells I cast).
  - +1 [Bloodwell Vial](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bloodwell-vial) (bonus to sorcerer spells I cast).

What bonus to DC will I get from these items when casting this Hold Monster?

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: At least related: [What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106182/52137), [Can a spell being cast via a magic item be considered to be more than one class' spell at the same time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141543/52137), [Does Wand of the War Mage apply to spells cast from other magic items?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/92192/52137)

Comment: I noticed you added the adventures league tag. That can't be right, can it?

Comment: It was suggested to me by NautArch (but the post he/she suggested it in is now deleted). It was suggested because in one of the comments below I said I care about the answer to have sufficient Rules support to hold when one would play at AL tables.

Answer (score 1):

The staffs details state:

> While holding the staff, you can use an action to expend some of its Charges to cast one of the following Spells from it, **using your spell save DC and Spellcasting ability**

When you chose to cast a spell from the staff, you use your own spellcasting ability, whichever that is.  You attuned as an Artificer, so you would use the artificers spell save DC and spellcasting ability, with the +3 bonus to Artificer spells.  Some of these spells are not on the Artificers list of spells, but the artificer ignores "all class, race, spell, and level requirements on attuning to or using a magic item," so it is no problem for them to use any part of this item.
Say you are a wizard 10/sorcerer 10.  When you cast the spell through the staff, you can choose to use your wizard spell save DC and spellcasting ability, or your sorcerer spell save DC and spellcasting ability, to take advantage of whatever you are attuned to.

Comment: Are you sure about the opening sentence? In particular Artificer's get at level 14 Magic Item Savant which includes: "You ignore all class, race, spell, and level requirements on attuning to or using a magic item."

Comment: Artificier can attune to the staff, see that characters "Magic Item Savant" ability. I am interested specifically in the Artificier scenario. Are you saying that if I use my Artificier spell save DC, then Hold Monster will be an Artificier spell for me, even though it is not on Artificier's spell list?

Comment: Whoops! corrected now, that was my mistake.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But you still didn't say what bonus to the DC would I get from these 3 other items I am attuned to and holding in my example. Will I get +3, +2, +1 or +0? Or maybe even more (if a spell can be considered to belong to multiple classes at the same time)

Comment: @melh "using the Artificer spell save DC and Spellcasting ability" includes the boost to those numbers by the +3 all purpose tool.

Comment: I would like to agree, but I am not sure if that will hold when I'll play AL at various tables. Isn't there a problem that Hold Monster is not on Artificier spell list? Everywhere else in the book when a new spell is added to a spell list it is said explicitly "this spell will count as _this_class_ spell for you" (e.g. in Additional Magical Secrets of Bards), but here something like this is not said by the book. Plus technically I am using Int Spell save DC and Spellcasting ability, not Artificiers. I am just afraid this answer won't hold up without some stronger Rules support.

Comment: Explaining how and why  you'd get to choose would be a great addition here.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are asking about. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @melh why do you feel an artificer can't cast it? the magic item savant ability specifically says you ignore spell requirements, why is that not enough?

Comment: I am not saying that Artificer cannot cast Hold Monster from staff of power. I am just saying, that it may not be considered an Artificer spell, when Artificer casts it. Plus for players Spell Save DC and Spellcasting ability, here INT is used not the Artificer class (spell save DC depends on INT and total lvl, not lvl in Artificer class). Also Sorcerer5/Druid15 could attune to staff of power and AFAIK use WIS when casting spells from it. But then would all the spells that player casts be Druid spells at the time of casting?

Answer (score -1):

### A spell cast from a magic item is from no class.

A spell doesn't inherently have a class, since it can be found on the spell list for multiple classes (for example Cure Wounds is on the Artificier, Cleric and Druid list); when a Cleric prepares it, it counts as a Cleric spell, when an Artificier prepares it, it counts as an Artificier spell, and so on. A Cleric/Artificier multiclass can prepare it either as a Cleric or Artificier spell, depending on which number of spells prepared it counts against.

If the same Cleric/Artificier casts Cure Wounds from a magic item, it counts neither as a Cleric spell or an Artificier spell, since the spellcaster didn't prepare that instance of the spell and so didn't choose from which class it should be prepared from.

In conclusion, a spell cast from a magic item only gets bonuses that apply to any spell regardless of class; in your case, no bonus will be applied.

Comment: While I believe I agree with this answer, the answer should source its claims with citations from the books