# Can you cast two spells from a Ring of Spell Storing during the same round, using an action and a bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, spellcasting, action-economy

So I just got acquainted with the existence of the [*ring of spell storing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing).

If I had the [*beacon of hope*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beacon-of-hope) and [*sanctuary*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary) spells stored in it, could I use the ring to cast both spells on the same turn? Or would it count as 2 actions instead of 1 action and 1 bonus action?

Comment: Some related questions, if any of these answer your question, that would be great to know: "[How does a Ring of Spell Storing function?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76556)" and "[Can you use a wand to cast a spell after casting a spell as a bonus action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125885)" and "[Can magic items let you cast spells with long casting times as actions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91810)" and "[Is it possible to cast multiple spells per turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74039)"

Comment: Thanks for the reference, the first and last helped me to get how it works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### You cannot cast a levelled action spell and a levelled bonus action spell in the same turn.<sup>1</sup>

The type of action required to use the ring of spell storing is determined by the timing of the spell being cast. From the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on [activating an item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#ActivatinganItem):

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, unless the item's description says otherwise. **The spell uses its normal casting time**, range, and duration, and the user of the item must concentrate if the spell requires concentration.

In this case, *beacon of hope* has a casting time of 1 Action, and *sanctuary* has a casting time of 1 Bonus Action.

You cannot do this, the [rules for bonus action spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell) state:

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. **You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.**

---

<sup>1</sup>Here, "levelled" means "having a spell level of 1st or higher".

Comment: But what about a multiclass Fighter/spellcaster that takes an Action Surge after casting first spell from the ring and then uses his extra action to cast the other spell?

Comment: Do you see anywhere in the description of Action Surge that changes the rules mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @Whizshade the issue this answer highlights is that once a bonus action spell is cast on a turn, all other spells cast on that turn *must* be cantrips, regardless of the ordering of actions, or availability of any additional actions.

Comment: This question has a great table that should answer your question: [Which uses of Bonus-Action spellcasting are legal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133767/62294)

Comment: That really summed it up neatly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

## You cannot cast two leveled spells per turn that way

The ring of spell storing says:

> The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell Attack bonus, and Spellcasting Ability of the original caster, but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell.

Nothing in the description of the ring does it say that an action must be used to cast a spell from the ring. Therefore, "otherwise treated as if you cast the spell" suggests that you need to use an action, bonus action or reaction as appropriate, to cast the spell. This is strictly determined by the requirements of the spell to be cast.

The rules on spells cast as bonus actions state however, that in addition to such a spell, you can only cast a **cantrip** having a casting time of one action. You cannot, therefore, cast *sanctuary* (one bonus action) and and *beacon of hope* (1 action, not a cantrip) on the same turn.
This is a result of the rules for spellcasting, however, nothing caused by the way the spells are cast from the ring.