Can I counter an opponent's attempt to counter my own spell (while casting with spell slots only)?
In the 2024 update to D&D 5e, the rule limiting the casting of multiple spells per turn has changed:

One Spell with a Spell Slot per Turn
On a turn, you can expend only one spell slot to cast a spell. This
rule means you can’t, for example, cast a spell with a spell slot
using the Magic action and another one using a Bonus Action on the
same turn.

Additionally, reactions are described as follows:

A Reaction is a special action taken in response to a trigger defined in the Reaction’s description. You can take a Reaction on another creature’s turn, and if you take it on your turn, you can do so even if you also take an action, a Bonus Action, or both. Once you take a Reaction, you can’t take another one until the start of your next turn.

Suppose I am casting Fireball as an action on my turn, and an enemy begins casting Counterspell to counter it. Can I cast Counterspell using my reaction to counter their spell and then complete my casting of Fireball, or does the "One Spell with a Spell Slot per Turn" rule prevent me from doing this, since both spells would be cast on my turn?
(Assume I am casting all spells using spell slots and not via some other feature or item.)

(Essentially, this is the 2024 update of this question.)

Your question has a clear stipulation: The original spell is using a spell slot. If that wasn't there the answers to this question would be different, it would be "Yes you can, if you haven't used a spell slot this turn". Therefore I suggest adding this stipulating to the title "Can I counter an opponent's attempt to counter my own spell, if the spell I am casting would consume a spell slot?"

@TreeSpawned Ok, I edited it.

You CAN counterspell the counterspell, but it would mean you can no longer cast your original spell.
Unfortunately, it does seem like the rules on this have changed. The "Specific beats General" rule does still exist (under the new term "Exceptions Supersede General"). But there is nothing contradictory here. Per the rules you quoted, you can only cast a single spell using a spell slot per turn. The rules for a Reaction do not say differently. They just say that you can take a Reaction if you've already taken an Action and/or a Bonus Action. It does not specify anything about spells, or the ability to cast multiple slotted spells on your turn.
However, Counterspell now states:

On a failed save, the spell dissipates with no effect, and the action, Bonus Action, or Reaction used to cast it is wasted. If that spell was cast with a spell slot, the slot isn’t expended.

(Emphasis mine)
This changes things slightly, but does not change the outcome. If you plan on casting Fireball and notice that an enemy is going to cast Counterspell, you can cast your own Counterspell to stop them. This is because the spell slot for Fireball has not yet been used, given that if their Counterspell had worked, you wouldn't have used your spell slot. This, combined with the description in longer casting times stating "If your Concentration is broken, the spell fails, but you don’t expend a spell slot", lets us safely assume that spells do not expend their spell slot until they are completed.
However, this does not change the fact that you just spent a spell slot using Counterspell. The situation is now that you are left with a spent level 3 spell slot, which means you cannot finish casting Fireball, and all the enemy has lost is their Reaction.
Effectively, using Counterspell on an enemy's Counterspell leaves you in a worse situation than if you had simply let them finish their Counterspell, since then at least they would have used a spell slot of some sort. This is different, of course, if an ally casts Counterspell instead, allowing your original spell to go through after the enemy's gets stopped.

I agree with your reasoning that a spell slot is not expended until the spell is complete based on the wording in counterspell.  But it would be great to get a positive confirmation of that at some other point in the rules.  For example, do spells that require more than one turn to cast not cost your slot if they are interrupted by a failed Concentration save?

@Kirt you're right. Luckily, the rules do clarify that. So I'll add it in.

This would also make features that allow a free casting of a spell without using a spell slot very valuable if you suspect you will encounter enemy casters.

The new caster meta: casting focus in one hand, scroll of counterspell in the other.

@RyanC.Thompson, You're right, especially since scrolls of counterspell can be crafted in downtime with proficiencies in calligraphers supplies and/or arcana.

Technically, you don't need to be holding a scroll. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131678/can-i-cast-a-spell-from-a-spell-scroll-without-holding-it Yet another use for a familiar.
