# Does the Storm Sorcerer's Heart of the Storm feature work with the Wand of Lightning Bolts?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, class-feature, sorcerer

The description for the [Storm Sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#StormSorcery)'s 6th-level [Heart of the Storm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#HeartoftheStorm-514) feature says "whenever you start casting a spell of first level or higher".

The [Wand of Lightning Bolts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-lightning-bolts) casts the [Lightning Bolt](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lightning-bolt) spell at third level if 1 charge is expended (or at a higher level if more charges are expended). Would this trigger Heart of the Storm?

Comment: Related: [Does casting a spell from an item allow you to apply class abilities that are used when casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50054/33707)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, Heart of the Storm works with wands

> In addition, **whenever you start casting** a spell of 1st level or higher that deals lightning or thunder damage, stormy magic erupts from you.

All the feature requires is that you start casting a spell that meets the requirements. And using a wand is still casting a spell, just with the aid of an item.

Specifically the Wand of Lightning Bolts says:

> While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 or more of its charges to **cast** the *lightning bolt* spell (save DC 15) from it.

Casting a spell is casting a spell. So it counts.

And the spell meets the other requirements as well since it deals lightning damage and is of the appropriate level.

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item, often by expending charges from it. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell and caster level...

Since *lightning bolt* is a 3rd level spell, that is what it is cast as, which meets the 1st level or higher requirement.

The fact that the spell is being cast with a wand and uses a charge has no effect on the ability for it to work here.