# Is it possible for a caster to have 2 castings of Foresight active?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, optimization, divination

The Foresight spell specifically includes the following caveat:

> This spell immediately ends if you cast it again before its duration
> ends.

Looking at this, I figured the only way to avoid that issue was to be a Sorcerer with the Twinned Spell metamagic, however, Foresight is not on the Sorcerer's spell list. I also could not find a way to get it onto their list within the bounds of 20 levels.

Is there any combination of classes or features within the rules that would permit a single caster to allow 2 targets (or more) to simultaneously benefit from Foresight?

Comment: Though there's maybe a pedantry point here: are you going for two castings of *foresight*, or the spell active on two creatures at the same time? (Twinned Spell makes a singular casting affect two creatures which is why it is applicable).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes

The main question is: **how reliable do you want it to be?**

### The unreliable option

A 9th-level sorcerer has enough sorcery points to twin a spell scroll of *foresight*; however, [spell scrolls have the following restriction](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#SpellScroll):

> If the spell is **on your class's spell list**, you can read the scroll and cast its spell without providing any material components. Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible.

Therefore, **the lowest level option is Sorcerer 9 / [Bard, Druid, Warlock, or Wizard] 1**. Unfortunately, a 1st-level bard, druid, warlock, or wizard can only cast 1st-level spells normally, so the following restriction applies when using the scroll:

> If the spell is on your class's spell list but of a higher level than you can normally cast, you must make an ability check using your spellcasting ability to determine whether you cast it successfully. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level. On a failed check, the spell disappears from the scroll with no other effect.

If the sorcerer has 20 Charisma (and chose bard or warlock as their single additional level), they only have a **30% chance of successfully casting** the spell.

### The reliable option

We need 9 levels of sorcerer to be able to twin *foresight*, as well as 17 levels of bard, druid, warlock, or wizard to avoid the spell scroll ability check. Since that is impossible, we need another option. The 8th-level spell [*glibness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glibness) holds the key:

> Until the spell ends, when you make a Charisma check, you can replace the number you roll with a 15.

The spellcasting ability check will be Charisma-based, if we choose a level of bard or warlock. **With *glibness* and at least 18 Charisma, the spell scroll ability check cannot be failed** (15 + 4 = 19).

But wait! *Glibness* isn't a sorcerer spell. Fortunately, we can use *wish* to duplicate *glibness*. Putting all of that together, we'll need **Sorcerer 17 / [Bard or Warlock] 1**.

### The mount option

The spell [*find steed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-steed) has an interesting clause that gives us another option (which works for [*find greater steed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-greater-steed), as well):

> While mounted on your steed, you can make any spell you cast that targets only you also target your steed.

Therefore, if you cast *foresight* while mounted, your steed also receives the benefits of the spell. *Find steed* and *find greater steed* are paladin-only, but a bard can use Magical Secrets to grab one of them. **Bard 17** can get you *foresight* and *find greater steed* without much fuss. Wizard 17 could use *wish* to duplicate *find greater steed*, take a long rest, and then use *foresight* while mounted for the same effect.

### The "cheating" option

This isn't *technically* what you asked for, but I'm including it for the sake of completeness. **Wizard 17** could use *simulacrum* to create a copy of themselves, then **the wizard and their sim could both cast *foresight***. Bard 17 could do the same, if they took *simulacrum* with their Magical Secrets.

Comment: Thank you for this very comprehensive answer. That's exactly what I was looking for. I've got such a huge blind spot with spell scrolls because they never seem to get handed out as loot in games I'm in.

Answer (score 5):

### It depends on your definition of 'feature'

Using a more liberal reading, spellcasting is a feature that can be used to create a Simulacrum, which can in turn cast Foresight for you.

Technically that isn't the *same* caster, but it is the caster (In this case I think a Bard or Wizard) utilising their features to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 2):

### Sorcerer 9/ [Druid, Warlock, Wizard, or Bard] 1 with a spell scroll

One of the big limiters is having the 9 sorcery points needed to twin a 9th level spell. This means we can't grab 17 levels of one the appropriate classes to learn the spell and thus cast it.

But we can just grab one such level and a spell scroll with *foresight* and, because spell scrolls have you cast the spell (DMG 200), we can twin it.<sup>†</sup>

---

†: See also: [Does casting a spell from an item allow you to apply class abilities that are used when casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50054/52137)