# Can you use twinned spell metamagic on a spell cast from a ring of spell storing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, class-feature, metamagic

[Twinned](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer) spell says:

> When you **cast** a spell....

[Ring of spell storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing) says:

> This ring stores spells cast into it, holding them until the attuned wearer uses them. The ring can store up to 5 levels worth of spells at a time....
> ...While wearing this ring, you can **cast** any spell stored in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster, but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell.

When I cast a spell from the ring can my Sorcerer apply the twinned spell metamagic, assuming he meets all the other normal constraints?

Comment: Related (possibly a duplicate): "[Does casting a spell from an item allow you to apply class abilities that are used when casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50054)"

Comment: It is not a duplicate.  The answer is not in the other question.

Comment: Yes it is: "You can apply class abilities to spell casting from magical items"  and "Can Metamagic be used on magic item casting a spell? Yes."

Comment: @SamLacrumb It definitely looks like an open and shut case for a dupe. If you disagree, youre welcome to open a meta discussion and we can handle it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, you can.

You can apply Metamagic to a spell that you cast through some means other than your own spell slots. The metamagic texts only say "when you cast a spell" (or similar language), so you can apply them to spells that originate from items as long as those items say "you cast" (or again, similar language).

As an example, the Staff of the Woodlands says "You can use an action to expend 1 or more of the staff's charges to cast one of the following spells from it", and the Wand of Web says "you can use an action to expend 1 of its charges to cast the *web* spell".

Since the Ring of Spell Storing says "While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it" and "[the spell] is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell", you're casting the spell, so it's valid for metamagic.

Counter-examples would be the Necklace of Fireballs, which says "You can use an action to detach a bead and throw it [...] the bead detonates as a 3rd-level *fireball* spell", or the Armor of Etherealness, which lets you "gain the effect of the *etherealness* spell". Since they don't say you cast the spell, you didn't cast anything, and there's nothing to metamagic.