# Can you store a Twinned (metamagic) Spell into a ring of spell storing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, class-feature, metamagic

[Ring of spell storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing)  says:

> Any creature can cast a spell of 1st through 5th level into the ring by touching the ring as the spell is cast. The spell has no effect, other than to be stored in the ring.

[Twinned spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer) says:

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and doesn’t have a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell’s level to target a second creature in range with the same spell.

Can I use metamagic to cast a twinned spell into the ring, (meaning anyone can cast that spell twinned out of the ring) and if so are there any additional restrictions?

Comment: Related (possibly a duplicate): "[Can a Ring of Spell Storing make it possible to apply multiple Metamagic options to one spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104058)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No.

The Ring of Spell Storing says

> While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster, but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell.

It's pretty clear about what carries over from the original caster, and metamagic isn't on the list.

Comment: Could a sorcerer twin a spell they're casting *from* a ring of spell-storing, then?

Comment: Literally the next question on the main page. The OP asked both questions at the same time.  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185824/can-you-use-twinned-spell-metamagic-on-a-spell-cast-from-a-ring-of-spell-storing

Comment: However, there seems to be an implication that the reverse is possible - a Sorcerer could apply metamagic to spells being cast from a ring of spell storing at the moment the ring is releasing them.

Comment: @JKizzle Yep, there's a question about that specifically. See my previous comment.