# Can an Order of the Scribes wizard cast a spell from a magic item through its manifested mind?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, wizard

[Manifest Mind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/wizard#AwakenedSpellbook):

> Whenever you cast a wizard spell on your turn, you can cast it as if you were in the spectral mind's space, instead of your own, using its senses. You can do so a number of times per day equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

Could I cast a spell from an item (example staff or scroll) through the manifest mind if the spell is on the wizard spell list?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour]  and maybe visit the [help]  if you need any guidance in posting Q&A here! Happy gaming!

Comment: Just found this related one, maybe a dupe: [Does casting a spell from an item allow you to apply class abilities that are used when casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50054/63061)

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes, provided that the spell is on the Wizard spell list.

The DMG (page 141) under the section "Activating An Item" reports (emphases mine):

> SPELLS. Some magic items allow the user to **cast a spell** from the item. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, **doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots**, and requires no components, unless the item's description says otherwise.

Hence you are actually casting a spell using the item and you are not using any of your slots.

The Manifest Mind feature says (emphasis mine):

> Whenever you cast a **wizard** spell on your turn, [...]

and it does not require using a spell slot: hence, you can employ it while casting a spell from a magic item.

Pay attention that the spell cast must be on the wizard spell list: if for example your wizard has the [Staff of the Swarming Insects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4766-staff-of-swarming-insects), then they are able to cast both [*Giant Insect*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/giant-insect) and [*Insect Plague*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/insect-plague), but since they are not on the Wizard spell list they cannot be cast by Manifest Mind feature.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

Any spell that is a "wizard spell" is compatible with Manifest Mind. The real question is then : can a spell cast from an item be a class spell?

[This Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106182/77044) seems to indicate that a spell is a class spell if it is listed in the spell list of said class. This means that any spell that is present in the wizard spell list is a wizard spell, which in turns makes it compatible with Manifest Mind.